# How To Merge And Sort Two Arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

Here I have two arrays. that comes from SQL query.
Two tables, but they have same columns like this.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"] => "1"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table A no.1"
    ["sort"] => "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"] => "2"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table A no.2"
    ["sort"] => "2"
  }
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"] => "1"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table B no.1"
    ["sort"] => "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"] => "2"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table B no.2"
    ["sort"] => "2"
  }
}
```

I wrote down what I wanted to do.

1. merge two arrays in one array.
2. add new property "type" to array children.
3. sort to array by specified key.

Finally I would like to get an array like this.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => "1"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table A no.1"
    ["sort"] => "1"
    ["type"] => "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => "1"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table B no.1"
    ["sort"] => "1"
    ["type"] => "B"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => "2"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table A no.2"
    ["sort"] => "2"
    ["type"] => "A"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => "2"
    ["name"] => "I'm from table B no.2"
    ["sort"] => "2"
    ["type"] => "B"
  }
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Use `UNION` in query, you will get one array.

Comment: Show the SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort your final results by `id` and by `type` making smaller ids come first and push table `A` row in case of collision, then you can use `order by` clause passing 2 columns for sort order. So, first it will sort by `id` and in case of a `collision`, it will sort by `type`.

```
select * 
from (
      select id,name,sort,"A" as type
      from A
      UNION
      select id,name,sort,"B" as type
      from B
     ) derived
order by id,type;
```

Comment: thank you!! I choice this query then get expected arrays.

Answer (score 1):

USING **SQL** with **UNION** query you can do something like this-

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT id, name, sort, "A" as type from TableA ORDER BY sort ASC
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, name, sort, "B" as type from TableB ORDER BY sort ASC
) union_result ORDER BY id,type
```

USING **PHP**, with `array_merge_recursive()`,`array_map()` and `array_multisort()`

```
<?php
$ar1 = array(array("id" => 1,"name"=>"I'm from table A no.1","sort"=>1),array("id" => 2,"name"=>"I'm from table A no.2","sort"=>2));
$ar2 = array(array("id" => 1,"name"=>"I'm from table B no.1","sort"=>1),array("id" => 2,"name"=>"I'm from table B no.2","sort"=>2));

$ar1 = array_map(function($arr){
    return $arr + ['type' => 'A'];
}, $ar1);

$ar2 = array_map(function($arr){
    return $arr + ['type' => 'B'];
}, $ar2);

$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
array_multisort($result);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/dURrf

Comment: Records in this case will be sorted in tables. I suppose OP needs sorting for result of UNION.

Comment: @u_mulder Agreed sir, **EDITED**, thanks for pointing me out :)